# Jackson mapper not map class inside arrayList

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jackson, pojo

if I have this POJO:

```
class Day {
   val meals: MutableList<Meal> = mutableListOf()
   lateinit val meal: Meal
}
```

and

```
class Meal {

}
```

If I try to convert an `HashMap` `map` representing the `Day` model, like this:

```
val obj = objectMapper.convertValue(map, Day::class.java)
```

Jackson convert to meal only the variable `meal` and not the list. Instead, `meals` will be an arrayList of `HashMap`.

I tried to convert manually every Hashmap inside `meals` to a `Meal` object and it worked, so the Hashmap inside can be converted to `Meal` and there are no errors.

What I'm trying to find is how to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet for reference same:

```
extractObjectWithTypeReference(data,new TypeReference<DataListUploadRequest<MakeModelUploadData>>(){});
```

create below generic method:

```
public static <T> T extractObjectWithTypeReference(Object object,TypeReference<?> typeReference) {
    return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(object,typeReference);
}
```

my class as below:

```
public class DataListUploadRequest<T> {
    private List<T> dataList;
    public List<T> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }
    public void setDataList(List<T> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }
}
```